# Unique user id code in php doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

Recently i was searching for unique username registration using php.. I came across a piece of code which i am displaying below:

```
<?php 
$fname=trim($_POST['fname']);
$lname=trim($_POST['lname']);
$email=trim($_POST['email']);
$usn=trim($_POST['usn']);
$dept=trim($_POST['dept']);
$pass=trim($_POST['pass']);
$tel=trim($_POST['tel']);

$dbh = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','') or die("<h3 style=\"color:red;\" align=\"center\">SERVER ERROR</h3>");
mysql_select_db('fy') or die("<h3 style=\"color:red;\" align=\"center\">SERVER ERROR</h3>");

$error= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stud WHERE email='$email' OR usn='$usn' OR tel='$tel'") or die (mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_num_rows($error) > 0);
{
    die ("Sorry! Either email, usn or tel already exists!");
}

$query="INSERT INTO stud (fname, lname, email, tel, usn, dept, pass) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$tel', '$usn', '$dept', '$pass')";
mysql_query($query);
$query="INSERT INTO log VALUES ('$usn','$pass',0,0)";
mysql_query($query);
print("REGISTERED");



 ?>
 <a href="login.php">LOGIN</a><br />
```

At this moment my database is completely empty. I've just created the database stud with the desired columns. Now the problem is when i try to register using my registration page, it gives me the error i specified in die that is

```
"Sorry! Either email, usn or tel already exists!"
```

How is this possible if there are no values in the database. In the registration form I've given

```
action="register.php"
```

as a processing file. Also I've tried with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, but i get the same error. Any help is appreciated. Thank you .

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: You're using mysql, which is deprecated. You should use mysqli instead.

Comment: There really should be a Flag option for SQL Injectable code..

Comment: Sorry i am new to php so i had no idea about it nor i am aware of mysqli.. But thanks for the suggestion.. Any link to learn about msqli  would be really helpful.. And if its deprecated then what am i supposed to use?? Where can i learn about it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that, as John Conde states, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Your second problem, and to answer your question, is probably because you have this:

`if (mysql_num_rows($error) > 0);`

instead of this:

`if (mysql_num_rows($error) > 0)`

Comment: Typo `;` is really hard to discover in your own code sometimes. Of course proper IDE solves that.

Comment: @Ryven Thanks a lot. I typed the code in notepad++ so couldnt make out